# Erro ao usar método getText() do Radiobutton

Tags: java, android

Criei um app bem simples para calcular uma conta com acréscimo de gorjeta onde eu informo um valor, seleciono um Radio Button com uma porcentagem e ele gera o valor final como resultado.

Mas sempre que clico em "Calcular" ele para de funcionar e fecha com o erro:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.exercicios.tipcalc, PID: 1870 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick>
>   ......

Segue o código abaixo:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText input;
private TextView output;
private RadioGroup rg;
private RadioButton rb;
private Button calcular;
private int op = 0;
private double valor = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);
    calcular = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcular);
}



   public void calcular(View view){
        op = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        valor = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());
        //output.setText(input.getText());
        if(rb.getText().equals("10%")){
            output.setText(String.valueOf(valor+(valor*.10)));
        }else if(rb.getText().equals("15%")){
            output.setText(String.valueOf(valor+(valor*.15)));
        }else if(rb.getText().equals("20%")){
            output.setText(String.valueOf(valor+(valor*.20)));
        }
    }

}
```

Esse é o XML da minha tela:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/output"
    android:text="carambola"
    android:layout_below="@+id/calcular"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titulo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calcular"
    android:id="@+id/calcular"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rg"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="calcular" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Informe o valor da conta"
    android:id="@+id/titulo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Escolha a porcentagem da gorjeta"
    android:id="@+id/titulo2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/input"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rg"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titulo2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="10%"
    android:id="@+id/val1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titulo2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="15%"
    android:id="@+id/val2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/val1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="20%"
    android:id="@+id/val3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/val2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="calcular" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está chamando um `rb.getText()` sem instanciar. Você deve acrescentar lá na sua `MainActivity`:

```
rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb);
```

Comment: Tem razão, instanciei da seguinte forma:
        rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(op);
E funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: @overRider Essa não é a forma mais "correcta" de fazer.

Comment: @ramaral desculpe, mas eu só estou seguindo a lógica que ele iniciou. Não vem ao caso nesta questão a forma "'correcta' de fazer" e sim ajuda para resolver a situação para dar continuidade do desenvolvimento. Eu fiz minha parte! Abs

Comment: Veja que o meu comentário começa com @overRider, eu refiro-me ao que ele diz no comentário e não à sua resposta.

Comment: Entendi @ramaral legal a forma que você fez. Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Você está a tentar aceder a um método num objecto que é nulo(RadioButton rb).

Você pode resolver isso ou implementar o método `calcular()` de outra forma.

O valor retornado pelo método `rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` é o `id` do *RadioButton* seleccionado. Ele é aquele que foi indicada na declaração do *RadioButon* no *xml*, pelo atributo `android:id=""`

Para saber qual o *RadioButton* seleccionado, compare o valor de `op` com cada um desses `id's`

Altere o método `calcular()` assim:

```
public void calcular(View view){
    op = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    valor = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());
    //output.setText(input.getText());
    if(op == R.id.val1){
        output.setText(String.valueOf(valor+(valor*.10)));
    }else if(op == R.id.val2){
        output.setText(String.valueOf(valor+(valor*.15)));
    }else if(op == R.id.val3){
        output.setText(String.valueOf(valor+(valor*.20)));
    }
}
```

Ainda ficaria melhor se substituir esses `if's`por um `switch/case`